# Why does the number of unused physical threads fluctuate in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a .NET application which I would expect to have 5 long-running threads operating including the main thread. I can see that indeed 4 threads are newed up across the codebase, and I believe there is no direct (e.g. work item queuing / tasks) or indirect (e.g. Timers) usage of the ThreadPool anywhere. At least none I can find.

Running the app under Performance Monitor shows that the number of recognized threads stays constant at 5 (as I would expect) but the number of physical threads fluctuates between 70 and 120 over the course of about an hour!

Does anyone know why there are so many unused (as far as I can tell) physical threads? And why this number fluctuates?

I can't find any documentation that would explain this behavior so my best guess is that the ThreadPool balances itself to accommodate changing environmental factors such as free memory and resource contention but the numbers here seem excessive.

**Update**

A senior support engineer at Microsoft confirmed that the physical thread counter in use definitely only reports threads for the current process, despite the odd wording in MSDN. If an answer suggests this is not the case it will need to point to a definitive source.

Comment: This is impossible to tell without seeing the actual code. You might be using the thread pool without realizing it and, at the same time, the CLR might be doing some work.

Comment: It's impossible to isolate the code responsible without knowing the triggers of ThreadPool thread creation :) Welcome to my catch 22. This is a question for people who have seen and investigated similar issues and can recommend where to look for errant code or documentation that explains the behavior.

Comment: @HansPassant. I should have mentioned I did the exact debugging you suggest as we use our own managed c++ wrapper to a c++ library. The total thread count is 12 (5 managed, 1 managed c++, and 6 unmanaged). Still well short of the physical thread count reported by perf mon. I'd love to say that this is nothing to worry about but due diligence requires I can at least explain it.

Comment: Well, yes, you should have mentioned that.  Very unclear to me why you didn't edit your question.  Of course you won't get a decent answer when you don't.

Comment: Since the inconsistency exists whether or not the unmanaged threads are included in the count it just seemed to confuse the issue.

Comment: Not to ask the obvious, but looking at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf749bat(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to indicate that the physical thread count is for more than just your application.

Comment: @Vlad274 Even if you filter Performance Monitor to only look at your own process? If it's not filtered in this way what is it an aggregate of? All .NET apps? all apps? or a subset of either?

Comment: @JRoughan Not the way I read that line. To me, it says that those are the threads owned by the CLR for all its objects. It makes sense to me because the CLR is unlikely to report to PerfMon which physical threads are owned by which process threads. As for the aggregate, I don't know. The doc is unclear (to me). For me, this would meet my due diligence - unless there is a specific reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: I still need to know what this number is actually representing and why the fluctuation is occurring (the original question). As a side note the number of logical threads is slightly higher than the physical count but the docs seem to say that this value is app scoped, not CLR scoped.

Comment: Are you using Task Parallel Library by any chance to new up the long running threads?

Comment: @Mrchief No, not in this case, but TPL threads would show up as recognized wouldn't they? They're straight from the ThreadPool.

Comment: @Vlad274 You've had the greatest input so far, if you post an answer I'll accept it in place of a definitive one before the bounty expires.

Comment: Yes, and usually the pool is allocated a bunch at a time, not one or two per demand, so that'd have explained the extra threads but in your case, that doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: @JRoughan when you use "unused threads" do you mean "physical threads"?  i.e. not recognized threads?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I believe so but that's the heart of the question I guess; I can account for all recognized threads but the physical thread count is off the dial and I can't see any direct or indirect cause.

Answer (score 5):

Both ThreadPools and the GC create threads.  There is a [normal (or "worker") thread pool and an IO threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960958.aspx).  The normal threadpool will allocate new threads as it feels it needs to to keep the threadpool responsive.  It should create one thread per CPU right away, and probably one thread per second after that up to the minimum # of threads.  See [`ThreadPool.GetMinThreads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getminthreads.aspx) for the minimum number of worker threads the worker thread pool will create.  See [`ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads(v=vs.110).aspx) for the number of "active" worker threads in the worker thread pool.  If you have long-running threads using worker thread-pool threads, this will make it think the thread is in use and allocate another to service future requests.

There is also a maximum # of threads in the pool, so as threads recycle back to the pool the pool may kill some off to get back down to a # it decides is best.

There is also a finalizer thread.

There are likely others that are undocumented or are a result of a library you're using.

## Update:

I think part of the problem is confusion over "recognized threads" and "physical threads" and "unused threads".
Recognized threads are [documented as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zf749bat.aspx) (emphasis mine)

> These threads are associated with a corresponding managed thread object. **The runtime does not create these threads**, but they have run inside the runtime at least once.

Physical threads are [documented as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zf749bat.aspx) (emphasis mine)

> native operating system threads **created and owned by the common language runtime** to act as underlying threads for managed thread objects

I'm guessing that the term "unused threads" by @JRoughan refers to "physical threads"--those that aren't "recognized".  Which doesn't really mean they're unused, they're just not in the recognized counter.  As the documentation points out, "physical threads" are created *by the runtime*, and I don't believe you can tell from either of those counters whether a thread is "used" or "unused"--depending on what @JRoughan means by "unused".

Comment: ThreadPool's threads would be recognized. I have a doubt about unused threads, but threads running managed code would definitely be. As for the IO threadpool, afaik it uses completion ports so that it does not need to have one thread per sent request and instead just need threads when receiving data in order to run the managed code associated with those requests. But at the moment the managed code would fire, the thread would be recognized.

Comment: Doubt about unused threads?  How?  If they exist at all they'll show up in Performance Monitor, et al..  And yes, I wasn't trying to imply that the io thread pool has a one-to-one relationship with thread to request--just that it has threads in it, used and unused.

Comment: The OP reports that the number of "recognized" threads is low (~5) while the number of "physical" threads is high (~70-120). My doubt is whether unused threads from the pool are recognized or not. If they are, then the pool cannot be guilty.

Comment: @VictorVictis See my update, "recognized" means threads not created by the runtime but at some point seen by the runtime (i.e. unmanaged).  "physical" are the threads that *are* created by the runtime.  Neither of those performance counters alludes to "unused" (or "used") state of a thread.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I recognize I was wrong about those definitions. The pool, and especially long-running tasks, may indeed be the culprit.

Comment: I can't find any official documentation about a separate "normal" thread pool and I/O thread pool. AFAIK there's just one single managed `ThreadPool`. However, this managed thread pool appears to distinguish between two types of threads: worker threads and I/O [completion port] threads. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm also uncertain whether the GC thread is actually called "finalizer thread". It's probably true that GC generally runs on a dedicated thread (and it's probably always just one), but I can't remember whether this is always the case. GC seems to work differently on servers than on regular client machines, for example.

Comment: Read CLR via C# and Concurrent Programming on Windows.  Both mention the two types of pools.  CLR via C# also mentions both *a* finalizer thread and the GC *threads* (in Server mode, the GC can have one GC thread per CPU)

Comment: I say 'unused' physical threads because I can't account for them; the code does not have any in/direct ThreadPool usage that I can find so even if the count *is* the pool waiting it shouldn't fluctuate, it should rest at the minimum.

Comment: @stakx I updated the answer with a link to article by a member of the CLR team that differentiates between work and I/O thread pools

Comment: @JRoughan The threadpools start creating threads as soon as your application starts.  The Framework uses thread pool threads and the compiler will generate code that could use threadpool threads.  I added a link to `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` that can be used to see how many worker threads there are active in the worker thread pool.  The Framework is also free to create other threads, so I don't think you'll be able to account for every single thread.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Thanks for the pointer to that MSDN Magazine article. Although I feel inclined to point out that it's badly written. One moment it says, _"There are two implementations of ThreadPool"_ (which is already implausible, since that type contains mostly *static* members), in the next, the author refers to the I/O thread pool as _"this part of the ThreadPool implementation"_. I take this to mean that while there is only one `ThreadPool` class, it is implemented as two separate thread pools--but that's an invisible implementation detail.

Comment: @stakx I find the CLR via C# and Concurrent Programming on Windows to be better references; but you'd have to buy those--which is why I included the on-line link. Feel free to believe whatever you want to believe.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: I'm not after an argument. I actually tend to agree now, that when one looks closely, the `ThreadPool` might really be made up of *two* thread pools under the hood. (See e.g. page 759 of the CLR via C# book.) I only mean to point out that (a) that article is badly written, and that (b) for the present question, you don't even need to make the statement. Viewed from the outside, the `ThreadPool` is a single entity that contributes to thread count fluctuation, no matter whether it's internally made up of one, two, or a hundred thread pools.

Comment: @stakx Yes, it's really hard to find accurate info about some of the internals of .NET.  It doesn't help that it changes from version to version...  Jeffrey Richter as worked closely with the CLR team and Joe Duffy was on that team for a long time too...  I trust anything those two have to say.

Answer (score 2):

Things like this do not have a simple answer. You need to investigate either under a debugger or using ETW traces.

With ETW traces, you can get events for each thread creation/destruction, optionally with call stack.

CLR itself could create threads for itself (e.g. GC threads, background GC threads, multicore JIT thread), thread pool threads, IO threads, timer thread. There is another kind of thread: gate thread.

Normally you can tell usage from the symbolic name of thread proc once symbols are resolved.

For ETW analysis, use PerfView from Microsoft.

Comment: I don't tend to ask questions with simple answers :) I have done a fair bit of debugging on this before hitting a wall. This debugging already included PerfView but it's still a great suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: If you're already using Perfview, then you're pro. Go to Events page, check for IOThreadCreation, ThreadPoolWorkerThread events under Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime. You can select those event types, then hit Update button. You can save the results to .csv file. Also check Windows Kernel thread events

Answer (score 1):

Is the application that you are testing in performance monitor a stantalone .net application or an application under IIS? If it is a stantalone application, probably you add some extra lib/code for using performace monitor. It mays create threads.

You can use Sysinternals' Process Explorer to watch threads in your process. You can see which method in which module started the threads.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a standalone application and we have already used Process Explorer to confirm the numbers reflected in the performance counters. This doesn't help us narrow down *why* though :)

Answer (score 1):

We can only speculate of course. My own bet would be about [in-process COM servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Those, and their associated threads, may be created when you use classes that wrap COM interfaces, such as the ones for directory services or WMI for example. Since they're created by native code (even though it's wrapped within a dotnet code), they're not recognized as managed threads.

Comment: Those *could* account for the "recognized" threads, but not the physical threads.